# How to successfully login on webpage using SHA1 + PDO + Prepared Statement?

Tags: php, authentication, pdo, prepared-statement, sha1

I am fighting now like hours to figure out how to make possible to use SHA1 + PDO + Prepared Statement combination and still be able to log in to web page :) So my question is how to do so? Here is my code:

```
if (!empty($user) && !empty($password))
{
  $password = $this->doHash($user, $password);
  $stmt = $db_login->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account WHERE username=:user AND sha_pass=:password");
  $stmt->bindValue(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results_login = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if ($results_login['COUNT(*)'] > 0)      
  { 
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $results_login['username'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results_login['id'];                  
    return true;          
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

My function doHash looks like this:

```
  public function doHash($user, $password)
  {
    return sha1(strtoupper($user).":".strtoupper($password));
  }
```

So my problems are: `$results_login***` never processes with the `SELECT COUNT(*)` version, and with `SELECT *` version it processes sometimes, but not always. So how do I put it together to work as intended, result in true, and fill all the variables I need? Thank you.

Comment: Security note: You should make your passwords case-sensitive (remove the `strtoupper` around `$password` in `doHash`).

Comment: are you transferring user password as is? it's not quite a good tone. the common practice is to send user password hashed on client side, e.g. with javascript.

Comment: This is used in my program where I need to have upper case so thats why I have to use it :/

Comment: @heximal I dont see a point in it if I do it client with java or server side in code .. please focus on my question :) If I want advices about my code how to make if safer I will write so but thank you anyway :)

Comment: @heximal - are you saying that people don't send the password from a login form to the server?

Comment: in this case we must be sure that password hash value that inserts into table calculates with the same function (doHash). can you output $password variable value and make sure it matches the value of table field?

Comment: @afuzzyllama I'm just saying there is no need to send the original user password but hash of it is quite enough.

Comment: @heximal- Interesting, I've never done it that way, but I guess to add a layer of security it could work.  How do you deal with the salt client side?  I feel like that could be exposed and thwart the purpose of the salt in the first place.

Comment: Hash is ok- is the same 8d53dff5b01c7eab62cae3f45187e4b2b4ee3a54 in database and after doing hash in web - but still I got no results from $results_login ... (empty when echo them)

Comment: So i fixed the count problem but after I use rowCount it seems that fetch or fetchAll is not working in any way and still returning empty fields any idea what is wrong? It seems it is not working in every place not only in login ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL statement is only counting, it is not selecting the username and id, you would need to use this as your SQL statement, or something like it:

```
"SELECT * FROM account WHERE username=:user AND sha_pass=:password"
```

For your password binding, the following should work just fine.  I would also use `rowCount` and only `fetch`, not `fetchAll`.  Give this a try and see if it works.

```
$stmt->bindValue(':password', doHash($user,$password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount()==1){
    $results_login=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $results_login['username'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results_login['id'];                  
    return true;          
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Now it does not even go for ($results_login['c'] > 0) function - which fails ... and as I wrote in my question Select * did not helped either.

Comment: have you tried a regular mysql query in the console and make sure the data you are trying to pull is correct?  Is your password field long enough to fully store the hashed password?

Comment: Ok so query is ok now I missed comma - Hash is ok- is the same 8d53dff5b01c7eab62cae3f45187e4b2b4ee3a54 in database and after doing hash in web - but still I got no results from $results_login ...

Comment: `rowCount` doesn't need the `count(*)` in the query.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12413/discussion-between-tim-withers-and-byakugan)

Comment: So i fixed the count problem but after I use rowCount it seems that fetch or fetchAll is not working in any way and still returning empty fields any idea what is wrong? It seems it is not working in every place not only in login ...